Is disuse good or bad for a septic system?
I travel a lot for my profession, and there's no one else using the home while I'm gone, sometimes for months at a time. Is a lack of drainage to my septic system generally a good thing, or can it be harmful?
For example:
Does disuse improve issues from any cooking oils (such as butter) that have made it to the tank?
Does disuse improve issues from chemicals such as bleach, dish, laundry detergent, etc?
Does disuse prevent/resolve biomat issues in the drain field?
Can disuse in the winter lead to temperature drops that can damage the system from a lack of liquid water entering it, especially when the snow comes?
Are there any considerations or treatments that should go along with disuse in particular such as a way to "pickle" your septic system?
